# pdf.js running hello world in node app

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am trying a very basic example using pdf.js. All I want to do is render and display a jade template containing the hello-world code from the github. I am running this inside of a node application. The pdf.js file is the result of the ~node make generic command.

The template is:

```
body
  canvas(id='the-canvas')
  script(type="text/javascript", src="/scripts/dependencies/pdf.js")
  script(type="text/javascript", src="/scripts/dependencies/compatibility.js")
  script(type="text/javascript")
    'use strict';
    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

    PDFJS.getDocument('/tmp/util_ac.pdf').then(function(data){
      var pdf = new PDFJS.PDFDoc(data);
      var page = pdf.getPage(1);
      var scale = 1.5;
      var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.height = page.height * scale;
      canvas.width = page.width * scale;

      page.startRendering(context);
    });
```

My error message is this

Note: I set disableWorker=true because otherwise there is a .workerSrc error

```
    Warning: Setting up fake worker. pdf.js:1418
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:8000/docs/viewer:51:13
    at Object.Promise_resolve [as resolve].transportDoc
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code without `disableWorker=true`, because otherwise the promise never gets called, and also included pdf.worker.js in the project (the other file generated by `node make generic`) so I don't get .workerSrc error *(what was it exactly?)*. Also the `PDFDoc` constructor seems to be obsolete in the version of pdf.js I'm using - 0.8.0. Making these changes the PDF is loaded fine.